# Espeak not working on raspbian

Tags: audio

I'm trying to use espeak to say some text. So I do the command `espeak "Hello I am a raspberry pi"`, the first time I have no sound, and if I do it again, the bash is blocked and all I have to do is to cancel it by pressing Ctrl+C (and it's not working immediately). I already tried with sudo, with the same result.

I have sound with openelec on the same monitor.

Comment: I tried hello_audio, and I have sound. I do not have sound with alsa Front_center.wav either.

Comment: are your levels set correctly in alsamixer?